# Azure DevOps API Discrepancy between Run and Build Start Times

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am gathering statistics on Azure DevOps build durations. I am using multiple Azure DevOps API endpoints and noticed a discrepancy between the pipeline and build response payloads. While both endpoints return the same build *end time*, the [pipeline run endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#run) `createDate` value is consistently occurring earlier than the [build endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) `startTime` value.

Intuitively, I would think the start time of a build should be parallel with the start time of the build run.

I am using the two endpoints to retrieve data from the **same build** containing a `runId` parameter of 74 and corresponding `buildId` parameter of 2731.

Calling `{AzureDevOps}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/74/runs?{API_v6}` returns a `createDate` value of 2020-10-14T19:43:55.4471062Z and `finishedDate` value of 2020-10-14T19:49:29.1295883Z. Calling `{AzureDevOps}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/2731?{API_v6}` returns a `startTime` value of 2020-10-14T19:47:53.1064066Z and `finishTime` value of 2020-10-14T19:49:29.1295883Z.

Above the `createDate` value is starting 4 minutes before the `startTime` value. What is the reason for this discrepancy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pipeline run endpoint createDate value is equal to the build endpoint queueTime value instead of startTime value.

[Pipeline run endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0):

[image]

[Build endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0):

[image]

The pipeline does not start immediately when you run the pipeline. For example, if you don’t have enough parallel jobs in your organization, it will wait for the agent. You can also find this from pipeline logs:

[image]

If your pipeline has not started, startTime will not appear in the response of Get Build REST API. But you can still get queueTime and createdDate.

Answer (score 1):

I made a test for this too and I got these:

- for build

```
    "startTime": "2020-10-15T02:40:20.4766161Z",
    "finishTime": "2020-10-15T02:41:02.1443416Z",
```

- for pipeline

```
    "createdDate": "2020-10-15T02:40:09.5783822Z",
    "finishedDate": "2020-10-15T02:41:02.1443416Z",
```

And in my case I got different values in `startTime`/`createdDate` which for me it means

- `startTime` - time when build was executed. I checked logs and first entry is `2020-10-15T02:40:22.1518676Z ##[section]Starting: Job`
- `createdDate` - time when pipeline run was created, so it also include time spending on waiting for an available job

I had the same results for `finishTime` and `finishedDate`, however the same may apply here. So the second may include a time for deallocating agent. Last entry in logs is
`2020-10-15T02:41:00.1014543Z ##[section]Finishing: Job`, which is less than values from API.

Maybe more accurate results you will get looking at `timeline` endpoint:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{{organization}}/{{project}}/_apis/build/builds/7512/timeline?api-version=6.0
```

For instance, you can check there execution time for stage:

```json
            "previousAttempts": [],
            "id": "96ac2280-8cb4-5df5-99de-dd2da759617d",
            "parentId": null,
            "type": "Stage",
            "name": "__default",
            "startTime": "2020-10-15T02:40:22.1466667Z",
            "finishTime": "2020-10-15T02:41:02.19Z",
```

You can also use log endpoint and parse response to get first and last entry. And I know that this is not elegant solution, but I would decide for this because it gave the narrowest time range. And for that statistics for me would be important to measure the real time spend on processing my pipeline.